# Countless errors in simple program

Tags: c++, cout, cin

The errors go away when I remove the couts/cins:

> std::basic_istream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_istream_type&
>   std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with
>   _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_istream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_istream_type =
>   std::basic_istream]

And here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x;   
int y;  
int z;   
cout << "Enter number of girrafes" << endl;
cin >> x >> endl;
cout << "Enter number of elephants" << endl;
cin >> y >> endl;
cout << "Enter number of tigers" << endl;
cin >> z >> endl;
}
```

Comment: Can we get a bit more specifics (compiler, ide, etc)

Comment: Just so you know, that's only one line of an error (and not the most important one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >> x >> endl;` is illegal, it's basically saying "read into `endl`".

Just use `cin >> x;`.

Comment: @noleptr the tag is C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `endl` from the cin statments:

e.g: `cin >> x;` instead of `cin >> x >> endl;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't `>> endl` because `endl` is an output stream function: [endl](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/endl/)